# Number of vertices in vornoi diagram

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry, voronoi-diagram

Assuming general position, I want to prove that for a Voronoi diagram of $n$ points, the average
number of vertices of a cell is arbitrarily close to $6$ as $n → ∞$.

I am not really sure how I should do it.
One possible way is to do it by probabilistic method.

Any help will be appericiated.

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/115292/voronoi-average-number-of-vertices-6/115302

Comment: @lhf Do you remember why $2e = 3F_3 + 4F_4 + 5F_5 + \cdots$. ?

Comment: Each n-face contributes n edges which are counted twice because of adjacent faces

Answer (score 2):

It's not true in general. If the points are arranged in a square grid, the average number of vertices per cell will be 4.

However, for a random set of points, it's true. You can start by proving that the degree of a vertex is almost surely 3. After that you can use the Euler formula for a planar graph.

Comment: "It" not true in general" isn't true ! Have you seen that the OP says "points are in general position".